# jQuery selector can not find bootstrap's modal when modal is hidden

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I try to set a jQuery selector's value in the bootstrap modal, but it did not work.
I try to use chrome console, I still can't set the value.
Could you tell me how to make this work?

```
<input type="hidden" id="a_input" name="input-name">
```

then, I try to set this input val from jquery.

```
$ ->
 $("#a_input").val(5)
```

but, this didn't work.

I try to use chrome console,

```
$("#a_input")
```

I get

```
[]
```

Comment: Post the code of what you've tried and what you expect vs what happened. As your question stands now we can't really help...

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see an example of setting the input type hidden to have a value with Jquery.

http://jsfiddle.net/brainbolt/52VtD/4/embedded/result/

To summirize the jsfiddle

```
<input type="hidden" id="a_input" value="" name="input-name">
```

As you did but with this jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('input[name="input-name"]').val('value goes here');
});
```